# Change Response URL without Redirect

Tags: php, html, forms

Is it possible to change the response URL without performing a redirect?

The slightly longer story...

Due to a limitation with HTML forms the following does not work because the query string from the action URL is not submitted to the server:

```
<?php // handler.php ?>
...
<form action="handler.php?lost=value" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="filter-keyword" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="do-submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
...
```

So I decided to switch to using the post method and create a separate filter handler script which simply constructs the correct query string for the "handler.php" file.

```
<?php // handler.php ?>
...
<form action="filter-handler.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="preserve-qs" value="lost=value" />
    <input type="text" name="filter-keyword" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="do-submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
...

// filter-handler.php
<?php
    $new_url = 'handler.php?filter-keyword=' . $_POST['filter-keyword'];
    if (isset($_POST['preserve-qs']) && $_POST['preserve-qs'] != '')
        $new_url .= '&' . $_POST['preserve-qs'];

    header("Location: $new_url");
?>
```

Is it possible to achieve this without performing a redirect?

```
// filter-handler.php
<?php
    $qs_args = array(
        'filter-keyword' => $_POST['filter-keyword'];
    );
    if (isset($_POST['preserve-qs']) && $_POST['preserve-qs'] != '')
        parse_str($_POST['preserve-qs'], $qs_args);

    // Fake query string.
    $_GET = $qs_args;

    // handler script is blissfully unaware of the above hack.
    include('handler.php');


    // ???? HOW TO UPDATE QUERY STRING IN BROWSER ADDRESS BAR ????

    // Following no good because it redirects...
    //header("Location: $new_url");

?>
```

Comment: If you just put the `lost` attribute in as a `<input type="hidden" name="lost" value="value" />` attribute on the `get` form type, that would put that parameter on the URL.

Comment: Please don't write tags in titles.

Comment: Sadly, any `GET`-type parameters are cleared when submitting the form.

Comment: @Tomalak thanks for the tip, I will remember that in future :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes and no.

No, because to actually *really* change the URL from the server side you have to make a redirect.

Yes, because there are other solutions to your problem.

**Solution no. 1:**

Change your code from the first example into:

```
<?php // handler.php ?>
...
<form action="handler.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="lost" value="value" />
    <input type="text" name="filter-keyword" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="do-submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
...
```

and this should result in proper URL (with `lost=value`).

**Solution no. 2 (ugly one):**

Overwrite `$_GET` array at the beginning of the script to cheat the application into believing the GET parameters were passed.

**Solution no. 3 (about changing URL without redirect):**

This solution is probably not for you, but it actually imitates changing URL. It is not on the server side, but it actually changes the URL for the user. This is called `pushState` (demo [here](http://html5demos.com/history)) and this is HTML5 / JavaScript feature.

If you can use JavaScript and make AJAX requests, this solution may be perfect for you (you can eg. call whatever URL you like and dynamically pass data you need, even altering the values of the form fields you would submit).

Comment: Solution no. 2 is essentially what I had proposed in my question, but on second thought it doesn't matter whether the user agent URL is updated because as far as PHP is concerned will be correct. Solution no. 3 doesn't solve my problem but it is certainly an interesting one! That could very well come in handy in the future! I will have a play and see how well this works.

Comment: @Lea Thanks for the feedback. Ad. solution no. 2 - yes, correct, I have just spotted that. The reason you should avoid that is that in the future it will be much difficult to debug it. Ad. solution no. 3 - you should be aware that in most deprecated browsers (IE) it does not work and you can achieve similar goal with changing `window.location.hash` ([see more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)). Anyway, did solution no. 1 help you?

Comment: @Tadeck I agree completely with what you are saying. In that case I might very well need to use the redirect solution. I have also noticed that solution 2 prompts user to resubmit form upon refresh whereas automatically redirecting avoids this issue. When a redirect occurs with `header('Location: xxx')` does it force the web browser to submit a new request, or does the web server do it automatically?

Comment: `Location` HTTP header ([see docs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30)) is sent to the browser as the information about where to go to find content. The redirect happens on browser's side.

Comment: Thanks @Tadeck this has helped me to reach a solution. I am going to have to use a redirect, but I will create a very simple redirect script which avoids loading core files.