# How to pass query string to view (without redirect) in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my controller, I have

```
return ('view_name',compact('some_variable'));
```

I would like to pass a query string to the URL, i.e. instead of abc.com, I'd like to have abc.com?test=1

I know how to do this via redirects, but how can I do it via just a plain return view? I don't want to use a redirect in this case.

Comment: You cannot use `view()` to alter the URL, this is only possible with a redirect / JavaScript, you can read more about it in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6132274/9193055).

Comment: You can try `return redirect()->route('/', ['test' => 1]);` if `abc.com` it's your base path